# Implicits resolution with Scala-cats

Tags: scala, monads, implicit, scala-cats, for-comprehension

Example is taken from [Tagless Final in Mastering Functional Programming](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Functional-Programming/blob/master/Chapter10/jvm/src/main/scala/jvm/TaglessFinal.scala):

```
trait Capabilities[F[_]] {
  def resource(name: String): F[String]
  def notify(target: String, text: String): F[Unit]
}

import cats.Monad

def income[F[_]](implicit M: Monad[F], C: Capabilities[F]): F[Unit] =
  for {
    contents <- C.resource("sales.csv")
    total = contents
      .split("\n").toList.tail  // Collection of lines, drop the CSV header
      .map { _.split(",").toList match  // List[Double] - prices of each of the entries
    { case name :: price :: Nil => price.toDouble }
    }
      .sum
    _ <- C.notify("admin@shop.com", s"Total income made today: $total")
  } yield ()
```

In order to compile is, I must include:

```
import cats.implicits._
```

Without this, I get an error:

> Error:(21, 27) value map is not a member of type parameter F[String]
>       contents <- C.resource("sales.csv")

Two questions:

1. Type of `F` is not known in advance. But there are `Monad` and `Capabilities` define `implicitly` for `F`. Why Scala compiler cannot identify it without implicits import from the cats.
2. Usually I prefer to find a certain type and do not import all stuff from the `cats`. For instance, import only `cats.instances.list._`, to be more precise. What exactly is used by Scala compiler from `cats.implicits._`, in order to be able to compile this code? And more important, what algorithm you use, to find it?
3. I've also found, if I add `-Xprint-args` option, code is compiled successfully even without `cats.implicits._` importing. Can you please explain, how it affects it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What Scala compiler cannot identify without implicits import are just syntaxes. Instances are resolved properly without imports (because of implicit parameters).
2. Out of `cats.implicits._` you actually use only

   ```
   import cats.syntax.functor._
   import cats.syntax.flatMap._
   ```
3. https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5909

   > The option behaves like `-Xshow-phases` and **stops the compiler** after printing.

---

Without syntaxes imported you can write

```
def income[F[_]](implicit M: Monad[F], C: Capabilities[F]): F[Unit] =
  M.flatMap(C.resource("sales.csv"))(contents => {
    val total = contents
      .split("\n").toList.tail // Collection of lines, drop the CSV header
      .map {
        _.split(",").toList match // List[Double] - prices of each of the entries
          { case name :: price :: Nil => price.toDouble }
      }
      .sum
    M.map(C.notify("admin@shop.com", s"Total income made today: $total"))(_ => ())
  })
```

Comment: thank you! The question is: I thought, Scala can identify via signature, that WHEN method is called, certain implicit instances will be in the scope. And also should understand, that if for the F type - Monad exists, it must have, when is invoked map/flatMap and others functions.

Comment: @Alexandr Yes but "must have, when is invoked map/flatMap and others functions" means that you can call them like `Monad[F].flatMap(fa)(f)`, `Functor[F].map(fa)(f)`... If you want to call them like `fa.flatMap(f)`, `fa.map(f)` ..., then additionally you should import syntaxes.

Comment: Thank you, Dmytro, for clarifying it. Never thaught about it in this context.

Comment: can you please show, how to exactly invoke `contents <- C.resource("sales.csv")` inside of the for-comprehension, when syntaxes are not imported. Just vai `Monad.flatMap` function.

Comment: @Alexandr https://gist.github.com/loicdescotte/4044169 I updated my answer.

Comment: no, how to use flatMap/map, without for-comprehension, it is clear.  `C.resource("sales.csv")` must return Monad. According to the signature, there is a Monad for F. The question is, how would I implement the `income` function with for-comprehension, without syntaxes importing. At all. For instances the cats library is not used.

Comment: @Alexandr You can't implement the `income` function with for-comprehension without syntaxes (either imported or implemented manually as extension methods).

Comment: @Alexandr `implicit class Ops[F[_], A](fa: F[A]) {
    def flatMap[B](f: A => F[B])(implicit F: FlatMap[F]): F[B] = F.flatMap(fa)(f);
    def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit F: Functor[F]): F[B] = F.map(fa)(f)
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198197/discussion-between-alexandr-and-dmytro-mitin).